# How can I talk https to my local docker registry (sonatype nexus)

Tags: docker, docker-registry, sonatype

From the documentation found here: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/docker.html

I can conclude that I cannot create a private docker registry unless I expose it through https.

> Docker relies on secure connections using SSL to connect to the repositories. You are therefore **required to expose the repository manager to your client tools via HTTPS**. This can be configured via an external proxy server or directly with the repository manager. Further details can be found in Section 5.9.4, “Inbound SSL - Configuring to Serve Content via HTTPS”.

I have done all these steps (using reverse-proxy on https://localhost:5001 forwarding to nexus proxy registry with http connector). However now that I want to start pulling from my local registry, I cannot find a way to access it through https.

The following command which is describe here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-from-a-different-registry

```
docker pull localhost:5001/hello-world
```

returns:

> Error response from daemon: error parsing HTTP 400 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "\n\n400 Bad Request\n\n
>
> ## Bad Request
>
> \n
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
> \nReason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
> \n Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
> \n
>
> \n\n"

and when I try this:

```
docker pull https://localhost:5001/hello-world
```

I get:

> invalid reference format

Comment: Try `export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=0` and then execute the pull and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is:

either having a valid SSL certificate for the proxy you re accessing the repository through

**or**

creating a self-signed certificate and manually inserting it in the [Windows Trusted root authorities certificates](http://windowsreport.com/install-windows-10-root-certificates/) 
of the computer you want to access the registry from.

This should resolve any issues and relevant messages. Try accessing  https://proxyUrl:5000/v2 and you should now be getting a different message than before as well as be able to pull and push to the registry.